# Can I connect to servers (that I normally would connect to via SAS) via Python?

Tags: python, sas, remote-desktop

Ideally, I'd like to provide my credentials and run SQL queries from within Python on my local machine. Is that possible? See a few notes on my set up below.

Let me know if you need additional info from me before you can help!

My set up:

- I connect to a remote computer using Citrix (or Remote Desktop
  Connection) in order to access SAS.
- We use SAS Enterprise Guide 7.15 HF3 (7.100.5.6132) (64-bit) to access our data.
- I have both Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed on my local machine (not on the remote machine).

Comment: There's not enough information to answer your question. The ability to connect to the servers is simply whether or not your local computer has access and authorization to do so. Since SAS is running via Citrix or RDC it's unlikely you'll have that access from your local desktop as well.

Comment: @Reeza I was afraid that would be the answer. Is there a way to test if I have access via my local machine? IT is not very helpful when it comes to this so I'm flying solo a bit.

Comment: You can open the DNS settings in the virtual machine, recreate them in your local under Control Panels>ODBC Connections and see if it works. You may be violating your works security protocols though.

Comment: Within an organization best practice would be to request an install of python on your RD.  If they are unwilling you could try to find a portable version of python.  It may be the case that you are using EG to connect to a SAS server, which in turn accesses the data -- in such a scenario, the machine running EG may not be able to connect to the data, at all, or in the same way that the server does.

Comment: All, thanks for the input! It definitely helped point me in the right direction.